# pthread_create pass function with two variable

Tags: c, pthreads

Can someone help me to know whether it is possible to send to two different variables to a function which used to send in `pthread_create`?

```
void *handler(void *parameter){
    //some code
    return 0;
}
```

is it possible to have function like this

```
void *handler(void *parameter, void *parameter2){
    //some code
    return 0;
}
```

If possible how can I use this with `pthread_create`?
Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The `start_routine` of `pthread_create` should be a function of the form `void *(*) (void *)`.

This is the prototype of `pthread_create`.

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                          void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

> The thread is created executing `start_routine` with `arg` as its sole argument

If you want to send more than one parameter to `handler` function, then you can do it by making `arg` a pointer to a structure which contains these parameters.

For example you can do this:

```
struct Params{
    int i;
    char c;
};
struct Params* pParams;
```

Now, in place of `void* arg`, you can use `(void*)pParams`.

Comment: @MadiyarAbdukhashimov: You are welcome. Updated the answer with a short example.

Answer (score 1):

A function that acts as a starting point for a thread created by `pthread_create` **must** accept a single `void *` as a parameter and return a `void *`.

You need to create a structure with your variables and pass a pointer to that.

```
struct thread_data {
    int x;
    int y;
};

void *handler(void *parameter){
    struct thread_data *data = parameter;
    ...
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid;
    struct thread_data data = { 1, 2 };
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, handler, &data);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks I also had a mind to make a struct but I wanted to do it with that way)